# SignalR Fails when Machine Key added to web.config

Tags: asp.net, signalr

When adding a machine key to the web.config in my project i consistently get the following error logged to the console when creating a hub

*SignalR connection failed: Error: You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version undefined.*

Removing the machine key and it works fine

The js code is below (works fine with no machine key present)

```
   $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var userHub = $.connection.userTracingHub;

        userHub.client.CompletedProcessing = function (model) {
            if (model) {
                alert("Order was successful");
            } else {
                alert("Order was unsuccessful");
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $.connection.userTracingHub.server.hello();
            alert("connection set up");
        }).fail(function (reason) {
            console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
        });
    });
```

The machine key is set as follows:

```
<machineKey decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="xxxx,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" validationKey="xxxx,IsolateApps" />
```

Where xxxx is the key i've put in.

I thought this maybe due to scale-out mode not being configured but i've also tried setting it to use a redis server to setup scale out mode and still have the same error

Thanks in Advance,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, then removing the IsolateApps option resolved the problem. If you are using IIS manager to generate the machine key, uncheck the "Generate a unique key for each application" checkbox or just remove the ",IsolateApps" part from the web.config.

Hopefully this helps!